# Dropbox REST API: Can we Make Folder Names anonymous / not have uploading user's names on them?

Tags: rest, filenames, dropbox

Our uploaded files are all looking like this in the GUI:

All Files
Name
username rest of folder name

Can we configure these to just be:  "rest of folder name"???

Thank you.  I fear I may be looking at the very thing I need, but I'm finding the documentation a little obscure in:  https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_requests-create

We are successfully using the https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_requests-create REST api to create upload URLs.  When the URLs are used for uploads, we get the above kind of usernames tagged onto the left, which our client does not want.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about the difference between the "member folder" (with the user's name in the path) and the "team space" (without the user's name in the path).

By default, Dropbox API calls operate in the "member folder" of the connected account, not the "[team space](https://help.dropbox.com/teams-admins/team-member/team-space-overview)". You can configure API calls to operate in the "team space" instead though. To do so, you'll need to set the "Dropbox-API-Path-Root" header. You can find information on this in [the Team Files Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/dbx-team-files-guide).